# Making an NSButton follow ScrollView in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

I currently have an NSOutlineView, which has an NSButton above it. When the NSOutlineView scrolls, the NSButton remains in place. That is, it remains above the text, covering anything beneath it.

I am attempting to "pin" the NSButton to a point on the NSScrollView such that when the view is scrolled, the NSButton follows the content.

Is there any way to do this in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the button a subview of the scrollView. Open the outline view in the left of Interface Builder and drag the UIButton over the scrollView so that it is indented

1. Open the outline view
2. drag the button so that is under the scrollview - it's not its subview

[image]

Comment: "Open the outline view in the left of interface builder", I'm not quite sure what this is referencing? I don't see an outline view to the left of IB. I'm using XCode 4.

Comment: Ah! I didn't even know that was there. I attempted to drag my button over the scroll view, however it seems dropping onto the "Scroll View - Outline View" is disabled. Here's what I'm seeing: http://i.imgur.com/LtDQk.png

Comment: where exactly do you want to have the button - in the outlineview like  in the picture above?

Comment: It's going to function as a "settings" type button, that i'd like to have beside the group name (directly to the right). For instance, on OS X 10.7, it'd be directly to the right of Favorites/Shared/Devices in Finder.

Comment: basicly it is the same concept you have to drag the button somewhere inside the scrollview as a subview. so that is inside/under the scrollview and next to your group.